# change data after aio_write to file request

Tags: c, linux, free, aio

Is it safe to change or free the buffer passed to aio_write for writing in a file. Or should i wait for the operation to finish?
Does the function copy all the buffer content to the queue or just the reference to the data?

Answer (score 2):

From `man 7 aio`:

> he control block buffer and the buffer pointed to by `aio_buf` must not  be  changed  while  the  I/O operation is in progress.  These buffers must remain valid until the I/O operation completes.

So you must not touch the structure until you have been informed that the operation has completed.